# Telegram Customer Service Bot

Tags: chat, crm, artificial-intelligence

**The purpose:**
Create the possibility of user / customer engagement within Telegram, so that users/customers can send us feedback / requests in a one-directional way and we can optionally answer to the querys.

**Some objective requirements**

- Create a new and meaningful message as soon as the user opens the chat with our bot/channel
- Create some sort of interaction by suggestion some topics via buttons which the user can select
- Autoreplying based on above button selection, i.e. in case the user clicks on "help", he should just receive a list of FAQs with answers.
- Multiple users shall be able to manage the customer queries
- Optional: Webbased management of the queries so that they can be closed as soon as answered and one does not loose track within all the open single chat-conversations

Comment: Are you looking for a piece of software you can install and configure yourself, a SaaS solution or rather some kind of API on which such a solution could be built?

Comment: SaaS or a stable API which I could control from externally, but this would need to run reliably for a long time. I don't wanna start fiddling around with the MT proto API and adopt my code base every few weeks or even months 